# Custom file type no longer showing in IOS mail app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app on the appStore called Quiz Maker. With this app you can create a quiz and then email your quiz to another user with the Quiz Maker application. 
To do this I created a custom file type called .qzm. 
This has always worked well for a few years but now when you email a .qzm file as an attachment it does not open up in the shared selection window (the window that shows icons for Message, Email, Add to notes, WhatsApp etc....

I've tried every combination of setting with UTExportedTypeDeclarations and UTImportedTypeDeclarations but I just can't get the file /icon to show when the user taps on the attachment in the users mail client ??

Heres my settings (for security I've changed my business name to com.myBusiness)

```
<key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Quiz Maker File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.myBusiness.quizMaker.qzm</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>qzm</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Quiz Maker File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.myBusiness.quizMaker.qzm</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
<dict>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <string>qzm</string>
</dict>



<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Quiz Maker File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myBusiness.quizMaker.qzm</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Heres a screen shot of my settings as a pList:

[image]

All of the above code does not have icons (.pngs) but I don't think makes a difference at this stage as a blank icon would show.

I would really appreciate any help or ideas to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - If you get stuck with the same problem, follow my code below:

```
 <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>inCommand icon114</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>qzm</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myBusiness.quizMaker.qzm</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>


<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>qzm</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.myBusiness.quizMaker.qzm</string>
        <key>UTTypeSize320IconFile</key>
        <string>inCommand icon114</string>
        <key>UTTypeSize64IconFile</key>
        <string>inCommand icon57</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>qzm</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/quizMaker</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: What turned out to be the important part of the change?

Comment: I changed the structure / order around a lot but what really made a difference was was the public.filename-extension followed by the public.mime-type in UTExportedTypeDeclarations. No idea why this finally made it work but it did.